# Angular 7 File Saver saving file with encoded byte array instead of converting it to CSV format

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

I am using [file saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) on Angular 7 to save CSV file returned from Spring Boot backend. Spring Boot returns CSV File object with some properties i.e name, size, type, and file content in a byte array format. When I open save page, File Saver saving file with byte array text instead of converting to CSV format and saving it to the file.

**getFileContent**

```
getFileContent(id)
  {
    this.filesService.getFileContent(SERVER_API_URL + "files/" + id).subscribe(
      data =>
      {
        this.fileObservable = data;
        let blob = new Blob([this.fileObservable.fileContent], {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(blob, "test.csv",{ autoBOM: true });
      });
  }
```

**Rest API:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/files/{id}")
    public CsvFile getFileById(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        return csvUploadService.getFileById(id);
    }
```

Comment: I think Angular 7 converting byte input to Base64 format. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the issue was with Base64 conversion by Angular. When `byte[]` data received from Spring, Angular converting it to Base64 string. I used [blob-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-util) to convert Base64 string to byte[] and then passed it to File-Saver. Updated code as follows

**getFileContent**

```
 getFileContent(id)
  {
    this.filesService.getFileContent(SERVER_API_URL + "files/" + id).subscribe(
      data =>
      {
        this.fileObservable = data;
        let contentType='text/csv';
        let blob = base64StringToBlob(this.fileObservable.fileContent, contentType);
        saveAs(blob, "test.csv",{ autoBOM: true });
      });
  }
```

Comment: thank you! I was having trouble with something similar and this solved my issue, I owe you a beer.